# Upgrade to 22.04 failed - ERROR got error from PostInstallScript

Tags: upgrade, 22.04

I accepted the offer to upgrade to 22.04 and the terminal window said it failed. I have done nothing so far. I could not find a log of what was shown in the terminal window but /var/log shows the following.

```
DEBUG Running PostInstallScript: './xorg_fix_proprietary.py'
ERROR got error from PostInstallScript ./xorg_fix_proprietary.py (g-exec-error-quark: Failed to execute child process “./xorg_fix_proprietary.py” (No such file or directory) (8))
```

There is only one thread when I search for the above error and none for 22.04.

I saw a suggestion to run
"sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade"
but wasn't sure if that was appropriate.

I was looking for a log of the terminal window because it said "apt-get check" failed, so I ran it and it seems fine.

```
sudo apt-get check
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
```

Could someone tell me where to find the log that shows the messages I saw in the terminal window during the upgrade.
I looked in /var/log/dist-upgrade but none seemed to show the same info.

---

After 14 hours and only 32 views (6 of them mine), I decided to try the
"sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" suggestion. I captured the following from the terminal window;

```
Setting up usrmerge (25ubuntu2) ...
Smartmatch is experimental at /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge line 172.
cp: failed to access '/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': Not a directory

FATAL ERROR:
cp --no-dereference --preserve=all --reflink=auto --sparse=always /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: rc=1

You can try correcting the errors reported and running again
/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge until it will complete without errors.
Do not install or update other Debian packages until the program
has been run successfully.

dpkg: error processing package usrmerge (--configure):
 installed usrmerge package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
```

and at the end

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 usrmerge
libdvd-pkg: Checking orig.tar integrity...
/usr/src/libdvd-pkg/libdvdcss_1.4.3.orig.tar.bz2: OK
libdvd-pkg: `apt-get check` failed, you may have broken packages. Aborting...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am not running Docker. But Docker seems to have problems with /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 too... see
https://code2care.org/docker/docker-m1-m2-mac-qemu-x86_64-could-not-open-lib64-linux-so-2-no-such-file-or-directory-aws-cli

```
/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge
Smartmatch is experimental at /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge line 172.
ionice: ioprio_set failed: Operation not permitted
chrt: failed to set pid 1645426's policy: Operation not permitted
cp: failed to access '/usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2': Not a directory

FATAL ERROR:
cp --no-dereference --preserve=all --reflink=auto --sparse=always /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: rc=1

You can try correcting the errors reported and running again
/usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge until it will complete without errors.
Do not install or update other Debian packages until the program
has been run successfully.
```

```
ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.35-0ubuntu3.1) 2.35
```

Because of the link shown below

```
FATAL ERROR:
cp --no-dereference --preserve=all --reflink=auto --sparse=always /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: rc=1
```

I checked out /usr/lib64 for the no directory message above and lo and behold it is not a directory???? Checking out /lib64 gives;

```
ls -l (in /usr)
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root 428384 Dec 17  2019 lib64
```

As /usr seems broken, I looked at the source /lib64 and

```
christopher@Boron:/lib64$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 42 Jul  6 19:23 ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

and it gives

```
christopher@Boron:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ ls -l
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 46 Sep  4 09:25 ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Isn't this a circular reference?

Comment: /usr/lib64 should be a dir, containing only one link, /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  Fix that.  All the /lib* files should be links to dirs in /usr.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Performed the following:

```
christopher@Boron:/usr$ sudo mv lib64 lib64-20220905-broken

christopher@Boron:/usr/lib64# sudo ln -s  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That solved the usrmerge problem. Thanks.

```
Setting up usrmerge (25ubuntu2) ...
Smartmatch is experimental at /usr/lib/usrmerge/convert-usrmerge line 172.
The system has been successfully converted.
```